# Information Absent From Careers 2.0 Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have set up a Careers 2.0 profile.  In so doing, I added a few of each: Technologies, Open Source, Apps, Reading:Books.  But only Technologies shows up.  Whether on edit view, Employer View, or Public View this information is absent.  What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a `!=` where I should have used a `==`.  Sorry for the issue.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: TIL !=!=== ....