# Profile items not displaying

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Information Absent From Careers 2.0 Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115154/information-absent-from-careers-2-0-profile)

My profile on SO Careers is not displaying any of the experience, education, etc. items. These items do however display when previewing a PDF.

This is seen using both Firefox 8.0 and Chrome 15.

[image: Portion of profile]

Answer (score 0):

I used a `!=` where I should have used a `==`.  Sorry for the issue.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: Wait, those are different?